# Rendering large textures on iOS OpenGL

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, textures

I'm developing an iPad 2 app which will overlay panoramic views on top of physical space using [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/).

The panorama images are about 12900x4000 pixels; they are being loaded from the web.

Right now the line to load the image is:

mGhostTexture = gl::Texture( loadImage( loadUrl( "XXX.jpg" ) ) );

Works fine for small images (e.g. 500x500).  Not so well for full images (the rendered texture becomes a large white box).

I assume I'm hitting a size limit.  Does anyone know a way to render or split up large images in openGL and/or Cinder?

Comment: Textures in OpenGL ES have to be powers of two last time I checked, things may have changed though. (Doesn't answer your question but hopefully helps you out)
And the maximum texture size varies for different devices, however the iPhone 3GS+'s max texture size is 2048x2048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for OpenGL ES 2.0:

"The maximum 2D or cube map texture size is 2048 x 2048. This is also the maximum renderbuffer size and viewport size."[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)

also, seems a solution may be present here:

[Using libpng to "split" an image into segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801478/using-libpng-to-split-an-image-into-segments)